# Windows 10 update stuck?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've been having trouble with Windows Update for at least 2 weeks.

Every time I go to "Check for updates", I see the usual stuff:

[image: Checking for updates]

For a few seconds, then the following screen appears for just a second:

[image: Preparing to install updates]

Then back to *Checking for updates*. After a little while, I see *Preparing to install updates* again. It does this 4 times in a row every time I *check for updates*.

It just seems to endlessly try to install this package, and silently fail.

Since it started seeing this weirdness a couple weeks ago, I think I have not received a single Windows update, it seems to be stuck on this package.

**How can I fix this?**

---

## Edit

As suggested in [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3119142), I located the program, clicked Repair, and it did fix the Windows Update stuck on this package.

But now it's stuck on another one:

[image: Creative Technology LTD]

Same, it flickers several times, and never installs it. I tried to locate the only device that matched this name (my Monitor Webcam), uninstall the driver, and reboot. But it did not help.

Comment: Manually install KB3119142

Comment: Try to [Repair or reinstall Windows Update](https://www.winhelp.us/reinstall-windows-update.html). If this doesn't help, do [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html). Please report on the results.

Comment: @harrymc I followed the steps on your link: I do have enough free disk space, my date & time are correct, the file system check is OK, and I tried restarting the computer numerous times. I did try the Windows Update troubleshooting tool. It always ends up with "Windows Update components must be repaired: Fixed", but the problem remains. The Dism tool completed successfully, but the problem still remains. The other suggestions do not apply to me (either because they are for other versions of Windows, or because I do not have the error code mentioned). I will try `sfc` now.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` completed with: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations". None of the suggestions helped unfortunately :(

Comment: Have you upgraded to Windows 10 or is it a clean install? In any case, when Windows gets corrupted in a subtle way, one solution is to do a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) which does not affect the installed applications (but ensure you have good backups), using a recently downloaded Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: It's an upgrade to Windows 10. I will try the in-place upgrade now.

Comment: If the problem persists, see also [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/resolve-windows-update-problems-5-easy-steps/).

Comment: The in-place upgrade finally fixed it. Can you please add an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible actions :

1. [Repair or reinstall Windows Update](https://web.archive.org/web/20210110145906/https://www.winhelp.us/reinstall-windows-update.html)
2. [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html) - check Windows integrity
3. [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

The last one in effect reinstalls Windows 10 but conserves all user data.
It is often used to correct errors arising from imperfect upgrade to
Windows 10.
You should only use it if all else has failed, and be sure to take good
backup before starting, and use the most-recently available Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: In-place upgrade is the only suggestion that worked so far. Thanks!

Comment: Note to anyone experiencing this: I had the same problem again today, with `KB3119142`. I did an in-place upgrade once again, but to my surprise, this did not fix the problem this time. So I found [here](http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/37532-windows-10-keeps-reinstalling-kb3119142.html#post535532) the following suggestion: *Go to Programs and Features and right click on the MS C++ 2012 listing there. Click on Change and then Repair. Restart your computer*. This one worked for me this time!

Answer (score 0):

Is the update shown as installed (even though you say it silenty fails)? (Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > View installed updates)

If so, try the following methods from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3119142):

> ### Method 1
>
> 1. In Control Panel, click Uninstall a program in the Programs group.
> 2. In the programs list, locate Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (X64) - 11.0.61030 or Microsoft Visual C++ 2012
>      Redistributable (X86) - 11.0.61030, depending on your system
>      architecture.
> 3. Right-click the entry name, and then click Change.
> 4. In the Modify Setup dialog box, click Repair.
> 5. After the repair process is completed, restart the computer if you are prompted to do this.
>
> ### Method 2
>
> 1. Run the Modify Setup repair functionality for Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable by starting the installer from the following
>      Microsoft Download Center website: 
>      https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679
> 2. In the Modify Setup dialog box, click Repair.
> 3. After the repair process is completed, restart the computer if you are prompted to do this.

Comment: It's not showing as installed I'm afraid!