# Windows 10 stuck during downloading updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I want to install updates for my Windows 10. But it stuck on 3% during download.

How to fix this?

`systeminfo` output (partial):
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed. [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2801 Mhz

Screenshot I got:
[image]

Comment: Before doing anything, whilst the PC is running, take a back for safety 

Comment: Relevant: [Windows 10 update stuck?](http://superuser.com/q/1044162)

Comment: It would help if you went to speedtest.net and gave us your download speed.

Comment: @Spencer4134 This was probably for several days. Download speed is 10-100 Mbits. Anyway I should mention it, thanks. I found the solution and described it.

Answer (score 2):

The following scenario helped for me:

Run from console console with admin privileges:
`net stop wuauserv`
`net stop bits`

delete folder: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution

Run from console console with admin privileges:
`net start wuauserv`
`net start bits`

Then start update again.

This is described at http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-stuck-downloading-updates