# Stuck in bootloop during windows update

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-update

Backstory: I am running a dual boot Ubuntu/windows 10 computer, and last night I left my windows on. When I woke up however, it had shut down for some update. When I turned it back on it said that it was upgrading windows, and when it got to the next step my computer rebooted. However, windows had done something with to my bootloader as I got a grub-rescue console ("unknown file system"). I booted into a windows install disk and when nothing I tried worked, booted into a live Ubuntu disk and reinstalled grub to make the bootloader work. Now I could boot to my Ubuntu and Windows again using the grub bootloader.

When I tried to boot windows it continued doing its update, and got to 75% (the moment where it starts to , and shut down again. But after rebooting into windows, the update still was at 75%, and does not continue and windows shuts down again immediately after the update screen, without any progress made. So now I am stuck here...

How can I get windows to either continue and finish its update or roll back the update? If you need more information, please ask, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you start Windows in [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)? This question may be of help - [Windows 10 update stuck?](http://superuser.com/q/1044162/97028).

Comment: I can not get into safe mode unfortunately, pressing f8 doesnt work, and this is what I mean by the update: https://youtu.be/4G8ixJwzbuo

Comment: Is disk GPT style or MBR style?

Comment: MBR (both my ssd with os's and hdd)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps:

1. Power down computer. Wait 10 minutes. Start computer. Setup will
   automatically restore your previous Windows 10 build or previous
   version of Windows.
2. Launch command prompt with administrator privileges. 
   Press Windows key + X Click Command Prompt (Admin) Type
   the following command:

   rundll32.exe pnpclean.dll,RunDLL_PnpClean /DRIVERS /MAXCLEAN

   Hit Enter on your keyboard Exit command prompt and Restart

Then, try to use the ISO file to do the upgrade:

How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10 ISO file
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43

Comment: I am not seeing how this answers the question. This appears to be a pasted answer. Please explain how it resolves being stuck in an **update**. They are not asking how to **upgrade**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However this did not work, because when I start my computer (after 10 mins of waiting) and choose to boot into setup, it does not automatically restore like you suggested and there is no option in the setup that does do that (or it should be done with the command prompt). Running that command pnpclean did not seem to do anything either (everything is still the same)